# Facebook like button not picking up correct thumbnail

Tags: facebook

I do not know why facebook like button is pulling a random image off the site homepage when I am specifying the image in the `og:image` meta tag.

Here is the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Keeper Local</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Keeper Local"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Keeper Local"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="KeeperLocal"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.keeperlocal.com"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://keeperlocal.com/images/keeperlocallogo.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Local shopping"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="KeeperLocal.com"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="http://keeperlocal.com/images/keeperlocallogo.jpg">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <fb:like url="http://www.keeperlocal.com/test.html" send="false" layout="box_count" show_faces="false" width="50" height="40" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This test page is at http://www.keeperlocal.com/test.html if you cared to view it live. Why is the `og:image` meta tag being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is too small. Facebook requires og:images to be at least 200px on a side. See the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.keeperlocal.com%2Ftest.html

Comment: Don't think so. According to the debugger the og:image tag is being "inferred" and so picking up the wrong image. From the debugger:`Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.` But the tag is there in the document head.

Comment: Take a look at the next line: `Tiny og:image: All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions.`

Comment: Yes, the image specified in the the `og:image` meta (http://keeperlocal.com/images/keeperlocallogo.jpg) is over 200px in each direction (207 x 207). But that is not the image that facebook is using. The random picture facebook has picked actually IS less than 200px.

Comment: I see you updated your image not from the 207x137 it was earlier. Now you need to visit the debugger again to reset the Facebook cache, and give Facebook about 1 hour for that data to be pushed to all their servers.